# how to hide the review form if a user has already reviewed on a product in laravel

Tags: laravel

am creating a rental house management web app whereby a tenant can only review and rate the house in which they are living in only. so in the view, I want to only show the form for the house when the user is logged in, whereby the user can only review that rental house and they can be able to see the form on any other rental house details page except for the rental house they occupies.
i just want only the user to reviewand rate the house they lives in and on the other house descriptions page they won't be able to see a review form.also a user should only have one review for their house house.I have tried this but it shows the for for other rental houses alsoinstead of hiding them.
this is the function that shows the rental house details

```
public function singlehsedetails ($rental_slug,$id){
 $rentalhouse=Rental_house::with
   ('housetags','rentalalternateimages','houselocation','hsesusers')->find($id);
    if (Auth::check())
    {
        $userrating=Houseratingreview::where(['user_id'=>Auth::user()->id,'hse_id'=>$rentalhouse->id])->first();
    }
    
    return view('Front.Rentalslisting.rentalhsedetails',compact('userrating','rentalhouse'));
```

this is is my blade file.

```
  @if ($userrating ==null)
                
            @else
                <div class="card padding-card">
                    @auth
                        <div class="card-body" id="ratingdiv">
                            <h3 class="card-title mb-4">Rate and Review The House</h3>
                            <span class="font-weight-bold font-italic text-danger">Note:You Can Only Review and Rate Your The House Once</span>
                            <form id="rateandreviewhseform" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" action="javascript:void(0);">
                                @csrf
                                <input type="hidden" name="houseid" value="{{ $rentalhouse->id }}">
                                <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">

                                <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                                    
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                                            <label style="font-size: 15px;">Give a Star Rating for the House<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                                            <div class="rate">
                                                <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rate" value="5" />
                                                <label for="star5" title="text">5 stars</label>
                                                <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rate" value="4" />
                                                <label for="star4" title="text">4 stars</label>
                                                <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rate" value="3" />
                                                <label for="star3" title="text">3 stars</label>
                                                <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rate" value="2" />
                                                <label for="star2" title="text">2 stars</label>
                                                <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rate" value="1" />
                                                <label for="star1" title="text">1 star</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <p id="msg" style="font-size: 17px;"></p>
                                <br>
                                <div class="control-group form-group" style="margin-top: 2px;">
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <label style="font-size: 15px;">Write A Review For The House <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                        <textarea style="border:2px solid black;" name="textreview" rows="10" cols="100" class="form-control" required></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    @else
                        <p>To Review and Rate the House Create or Log In to your Account...</p>
                        <span href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signupmodal" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Create/Login an Account<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>
                    @endauth
                </div>
            @endif
```

in my users table i have a column "house_id" that store the house id for the user[image: users column house id]

this is my ratings and reviews table [image: ratings and reviews table]

Comment: first of all your code will throw exception if user will not login because $userrating is not set empty and i am assuming you are storing reviews in Houseratingreview table then  in blade form must be in if condition not in else

Comment: @Shozabjaveed show me an idea of how i can set it up kindly

Comment: what is name of field that returns the user_id of resident?

Comment: i havent understood you sir. what's the resident?

Comment: you said in question that "tenant can only review and rate the house in which they are living in"  so i need database field name which indicated who is living in the selected house or share your database fields with me

Comment: ooh i undrstand you now..in the users table i have a "house_id" column that stores the id of the house of the user..let me edit in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function singlehsedetails ($rental_slug,$id){
     $rentalhouse=Rental_house::with
       ('housetags','rentalalternateimages','houselocation','hsesusers')->find($id);
    $userrating=null;
    $allowreview=false;
    $currentuserlivinginhouse=false;
     ////check if user is living in the house
    if(isset(Auth::user()->house_id) && Auth::user()->house_id==$id){
        $currentuserlivinginhouse=true;
    }
    if (Auth::check())
    {
        $userrating=Houseratingreview::where(['user_id'=>Auth::user()->id,'hse_id'=>$rentalhouse->id])->first();
          //if user is living in the house and rating not given then allow review
        if($currentuserlivinginhouse && !isset($userrating->id)){
            $allowreview=true;
        }  
    }
      
    return view('Front.Rentalslisting.rentalhsedetails',compact('userrating','rentalhouse','allowreview'));
}
```

Blade

```
 @if ($allowreview)
               
                <div class="card padding-card">
                    @auth
                        <div class="card-body" id="ratingdiv">
                            <h3 class="card-title mb-4">Rate and Review The House</h3>
                            <span class="font-weight-bold font-italic text-danger">Note:You Can Only Review and Rate Your The House Once</span>
                            <form id="rateandreviewhseform" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" action="javascript:void(0);">
                                @csrf
                                <input type="hidden" name="houseid" value="{{ $rentalhouse->id }}">
                                <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">

                                <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                                    
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                                            <label style="font-size: 15px;">Give a Star Rating for the House<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                                            <div class="rate">
                                                <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rate" value="5" />
                                                <label for="star5" title="text">5 stars</label>
                                                <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rate" value="4" />
                                                <label for="star4" title="text">4 stars</label>
                                                <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rate" value="3" />
                                                <label for="star3" title="text">3 stars</label>
                                                <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rate" value="2" />
                                                <label for="star2" title="text">2 stars</label>
                                                <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rate" value="1" />
                                                <label for="star1" title="text">1 star</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <p id="msg" style="font-size: 17px;"></p>
                                <br>
                                <div class="control-group form-group" style="margin-top: 2px;">
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <label style="font-size: 15px;">Write A Review For The House <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                        <textarea style="border:2px solid black;" name="textreview" rows="10" cols="100" class="form-control" required></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    @else
                        <p>To Review and Rate the House Create or Log In to your Account...</p>
                        <span href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signupmodal" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Create/Login an Account<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>
                    @endauth
                </div>
            @endif
```